# LINUX - wget скачивание с ftp

Tags: linux, ftp, wget

Не могу совладать с скачиванием файлов с ftp через wget. Постоянно скачиватся версия файла которая была скачена в первый раз, то есть как я понял происходит кэширование файла

Строчка кода:

```
wget -P /home/user/ ftp://user:password@ftp_server/files/123.txt
```

И всякий раз когда я правлю файл на фтп я получаю файл который был в первый раз скачен.

Пробовал всевозможные параметры и их комбинации. Ничего не помогло.

Писали про конфигурационный файл wget но у меня его нет. Если создать, то непоянтно какое содержимое должно в нем быть.

Гуглил все что возможно.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Содержимое каталога проверяли? Возможно wget скачивает в `123.txt.1`, `123.txt.2` и так далее

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30418188/4827341

Comment: в случае повторного скачивания, когда файл уже был скачен - да, в конце расширения идет инкрементация, но файл все равно содержит первоначальные данные (то есть то что скачивал в первый раз)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге была пробелема в том, что фтп при измении файла под определенным пользователем менял файл в исходное состояние.